# how to nest <% %> when accessing variable from code behind file?

Tags: asp.net

Well i have this which works fine

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="abc" runat="server"
Text='<%#Eval("artist") %>'
PostBackUrl='<%#"~/welcome.aspx?artist="+Eval("artist")%>'>
```

now i want to place <%= str %> in place of artist from test which is a variable .cs file

Can anybody tell how to do it ??

Answer (score 1):

An example for you:

ASCX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repItems" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlItem" runat="server">                       
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval(FieldName) %>' ></asp:LinkButton>                  
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>        
</asp:Repeater>
```

CS:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string FieldName = @"Name";


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ArtistInfo> artists = new List<ArtistInfo>();

        artists.Add( new ArtistInfo() { Name = "Lady GaGa", Location = "Nebraska" });
        artists.Add( new ArtistInfo() { Name = "Justin Timberlake", Location = "Memphis" });

        repItems.DataSource = artists;
        repItems.DataBind();
    }
}

public class ArtistInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Since `<%# %>` just means evaluate this expression and return its result during databind, you can put anything you want in there.  In this case, we are calling Eval with an argument of FieldName which is a string defined in the code-behind.